# How can a process with a 32-bit address space access large amounts of memory efficiently?

Tags: c

We have a process with a 32-bit address space that needs to access more memory than it can address directly. Most of the source code for this process cannot be changed. We can change the modules that are used to manage access to the data. The interfaces to those modules may include 64-bit pieces of data that identify the memory to be accessed.

We currently have an implementation in which the interface modules use interprocess communication with a 64-bit process to transfer data to and from the address space of that 64-bit process.

Is there a better way?

Comment: So.. you want your 32-bit application to have access to a 64-bit address space? Um... Any reason you don't just make a 64-bit application?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question.  It's unclear whether you're talking about code portability between  32 and 64 bit addressing models, or you somehow view using a 64-bit model as allowing you to  address more in a 32-bit space.

Comment: Or are you looking to somehow implement a paged/overlaid system so you can get more "addressability" from a 1G space somehow?  To do that you'd need to step outside of ordinary pointers and use a dope vector or some such.

Comment: @WhozCraig you understood my problem correctly, i cannot make a 64 bit application thats a restriction, do you see some method to do this in 32 bit space only

Comment: @HotLicks i am talking about code portability between 32 and 64 bit addressing models

Comment: I have rewritten the question as I understand it. If this is incorrect, you can roll it back to the previous version.

Comment: On all common systems that I'm familiar with, a given process has a fixed size address space.  You can have two processes on a system, one running with a 32-bit space and one with a 64-bit space, but the processes are separate and an address in one does not/cannot refer to a location in the other.  Any data sharing between the two would be via either message passing or page sharing, with the page being mapped to different locations in the two spaces.

Comment: (Actually, I'm remembering that OS/2 *tried* to do this, where code compiled for 16 bits could be mixed with code compiled for 32 bits in the same process.  IIRC, it didn't work out too well (and then, of course, neither did OS/2).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in various comments, the situation is:

- There is a 32-bit process of which a small portion can be altered. The rest is essentially pre-compiled and cannot be changed.
- The small portion currently communicates with a 64-bit process to transfer selected data between a 64-bit address space and the address space of the 32-bit process.
- You seek alternatives, presumably with higher performance.

Interprocess communication is generally fast. There may not be a faster method unless:

- your system has specialized hardware for accelerating memory transfers, or
- your system has means of remapping memory (more below).

Unix has calls such as `shmat` and `mmap` that allow processes to attach to shared memory segments and to map portions of their address spaces to offsets within shared memory segments. It is possible that calls such as these can support mapping portions of a 32-bit address space into large shared memory segments that exist in a large physical address space.

For example, the call `mmap` takes a `void *` parameter for the address to map in the process’ address space and an `off_t` parameter for the offset into a shared memory segment. Conceivably, the `off_t` type may be a 64-bit type even though the `void *` is only a 32-bit pointer. I have not investigated this.

Remapping memory is conceivable faster than transferring memory by copy operations, since it can involve simply changing the virtual address map instead of physically moving data.

Comment: On Linux, you can either define `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and use 64-bit versions of functions (e.g. `mmap64`) or you can define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` and use regular versions of functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer i will read more about mmap :)

Answer (score 3):

Very few platforms support mixing 32-bit and 64-bit code.  If you need more than 2 or 3 GB of address space, your options are:

- Recompile the whole application as 64-bit, or
- Use memory-mapped files to page in and out large chunks of data.

Recompiling is easy.  Accessing more than 2 or 3 GB of memory in a 32-bit program is *hard*.

Note that recompiling a 32-bit application as a 64-bit application requires no changes to your code or functionality, barring a few bugs that might turn up if your code has unportable constructs.  Things like:

```
size_t round_to_16(size_t x)
{
    return x & ~15; // BUG in 64-bit code, should be ~(size_t) 15
}
```

Comment: recompiling is not an option, i am restricted there, i need to find some other solution

Comment: Forgive me if I don't understand, but if you can't recompile, then how are you supposed to add code?

Comment: see this is a small module of a large code, so recompiling the whole code in 64 bit application is not feasible, i need some alternate solution

Comment: If your data does not fit in the application's address space, store your data in a database.  You can't run a 64-bit module in a 32-bit application.  (I mean, it's theoretically possible, but you can't do it.)

Comment: i will give you an example, consider a structure in 32 bits space
which has a pointer which points to some location in 64 bit address space. this location may contain any amount of data, but we can access that data using the pointer. so i am talikng in similar terms

Comment: I'm going to repeat this again: **you cannot run a 64-bit module in a 32-bit application**.  If you need more data than you have address space, **you must store the data in a database**.

Comment: There is not a separate 32-bit and 64-bit address space.  There is only one address space per program.  If your program is 32-bit, then that address space is 32-bit.  If your program is 64-bit, then that address space is 64-bit.  You could theoretically mix 32-bit code and 64-bit code in a 64-bit process, but I know of no platform which supports this.

Comment: we can actually have a code run on 32bit machine but use 64 bit address space also :)

Comment: Huh, what?  Since when?  Are you talking about emulation?

Comment: That's great, but you're talking about two different applications.  Each application is either 32-bit or 64-bit.  You can't mix.